# How do I stop MongoDatabase connection logging?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, replit

I have a node js web server, and hen ever I wake up the server, after MongoDatabase connects, it sends this to my console

```js
MongoClient {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] { newListener: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  s: {
    url: 'mongodb+srv://cookie:lmTMc*********@logs.4kn9o.mongodb.net/Logs?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
    options: {
      servers: [Array],
...
```

It sends this to my console, which because of where I host (repl.it), in some cases, the console is publically viewable. This is a problem because it shows my user password. How can I remove this log?

Here is the code for connecting to the database

```js
let client, url, database, collection, query;
async function mongoPrep() {
  try {
    url = process.env.MONGOURL;
    client = new MongoClient(url, {
      useUnifiedTopology: true
    });
    await client.connect();
    database = client.db("Data");
    collection = database.collection("Data");
    query = {
      name: "data"
    };
    await getData();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    console.log("Mongo Connection Success");
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share a snippet of the source code

Comment: @Minsky I added the database connectino function

Comment: I would remove client.connect() and do `client = MongoClient.connect(...)` there is an example in the docs, without using `new` supposing that's the problem

Comment: @Minsky i tried that, but it still gives me the long console log, with the url

Comment: can you include a small snippet reproducing the error that I could try locally? it's surely something we can fix

Comment: THe problem is in getData, include that function definition

Comment: @Minsky all of the code is in here. just go look at that. https://repl.it/@CookieGamer733/CookieGamer733#index.js

Comment: will do in a couple of hours, no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I was had console.log(connection) somewhere. I need to do a better job at reviewing my code (note i found this a while ago, but adding the answer now)